# Can i get back unlinked objects?

Tags: objects

i need help. I lost hour of work because i unlinked whole project, i read that “unlink” means “delete” but that it is still in file. Is there any chance to get it back? Or is it lost forever ?

Comment: If the data-blocks are in there, then you can add a new object and change the mesh-data and animation data etc. Here I added a Sphere, then I deleted it, but as you can see the mesh data still exists. https://imgur.com/a/qP02mi0 But if there is no user for a data block it won't be saved, so it will lost after you restart the software except if it is protected (with the shield icon). https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html